# Apache virtualhost configuration issue

Tags: apache-httpd, docker, apache-virtualhost, php7, symfony

I'm developing a symfony application and in trying to remove index.php from the url, I used the following virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/experiments-1/public"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The localtion of the site is confirmed as **/var/www/html/experiments-1/public/index.php**.

But when I visit *http://localhost:81/* I just get the default symfony page.

I would appreciate some insight into what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Did you reload/restart after making the configuration change? Is that the only active configuration file? Add the log entry for the access to your question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Yes. I did execute "service apache2 reload" after the configuration change

Comment: Do you not use the `listen 80`  directive at the top of your script as seen [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)?

Comment: @NateT: Including that "Listen 80" statement results in an apache syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is for port 80 but you access port 81.

Comment: I am using a docker container for building the site. So port 81 is the external port but I kept the internal port as 80. However, I did rebuild the container using 80:80 as the external:internal port but I still don't get the experiments-1 site responding at localhost